# A long process of particular page work halts the other page browsing in same site for other user

Tags: php, mysql, website

Could you help me to figure it out the exact reason for a website slowdown.

A particular website takes long time to load any of pages or does not show a page while the other user access report generation page and generates a report. This happens only when the report generation page is accessed/processed[ Report Generation page uses mysql + php based coding ]. Once the report is generated any page access becomes normal. The browser hangs only for this website page, other sites are opening/loading as usual.

Comment: Can _other browsers_ load pages from the same website successfully while it's busy, or do they wait as well?

Comment: Other computers same browser and other browsers too throws error on browser window  "Gateway Timeout
The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.".  The browser starts displaying when the processing page finish its work.

Comment: 1) Does it let you open a non-PHP page (regular .html or .jpg or other fully static file) from the same server? 2) What PHP mode is the server using (fastcgi, FPM, mod_php, fcgid, etc.)?

Comment: Only  PHP pages from the same server has problem. Other .html pages are opening shortly.

Comment: All PHP pages or only those which connect to the database?

Comment: Thank you grawity! i found out the problem, due to the poor script coding in php.

Comment: You should post some information about it as an answer, for future reference.